# Bug in diff: wrong words are marked as deleted and inserted

Tags: bug, diff

I would expect the words `" in this case"` to be marked as deleted. Instead `" properly"` is marked as deleted *and* inserted.

Live: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17378116

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That word was removed and inserted somewhere else in the sentence. Imo what highlight is perfectly fine. Or is there a reason why you would consider "in this case" to be more eligible for the highlight than "properly"?

Comment: I can see "in this case" in both shots. How do you suggest highlighting a moved word (in this case "properly")?

Comment: The editor changed `works in this case properly` to `works properly in this case`.You misunderstood the revision. Check https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46298491/revisions.

Comment: I totally missed that the text was moved. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a toss-up whether you move "in this case" or "properly". I think this is like the [Duck-Rabbit Illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit%E2%80%93duck_illusion).

[image: Optical illusion of a duck facing left or a rabbit facing right]

You're seeing the "rabbit" (in this case) and a lot of other folks are seeing the "duck" (properly). It's not actually a bug, just a different view of the same change.

Comment: right.. but OP seems to have seen half a rabbit."I would expect the words " in this case" to be marked as deleted"

Comment: @suraj I took that to mean 'I expected `in this case' to be red on the left side, not 'properly'" (although now I see the *and* part, I agree with you... regardless, it's just a misunderstanding)